MySQL 5.1 Time format of the 6-digit string
What time format is the 6-digit string in? Or is a transaction ID of some sort? MySQL server is 5.1.
Errors log
240110  9:00:01 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
240110  9:00:02 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
240124  9:00:04 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
240124  9:00:04 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Slow queries log
# Time: 181018 12:24:24
# User@Host: dms[dms] @  [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 1.210543  Lock_time: 0.000051 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 30758
SET timestamp=1539825864;
--
# Time: 181018 12:24:40
# User@Host: dms[dms] @  [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 1.186729  Lock_time: 0.000044 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 122775
SET timestamp=1539825880;
--
# Time: 181018 12:25:10
# User@Host: dms[dms] @  [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 1.207168  Lock_time: 0.000047 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 122775
SET timestamp=1539825910;


Here's the code that outputs the slow query log timestamp in the MySQL 5.7 branch:
buff_len= my_snprintf(buff, sizeof buff,
                      "# Time: %02d%02d%02d %2d:%02d:%02d\n",
                      start.tm_year % 100, start.tm_mon + 1,
                      start.tm_mday, start.tm_hour,
                      start.tm_min, start.tm_sec);

You should be able to see that the format is yymmdd hh:mm:ss.
For example, "181018 12:24:24" is 2018-10-18 12:24:24.
This also corresponds to the timestamp shown in the query (given some timezone offset):
mysql> select from_unixtime(1539825864) as ts;
+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2018-10-17 18:24:24 |
+---------------------+


String and Numeric Literals in Date and Time Context

MySQL recognizes TIME values in these formats:

As a string in 'D hh:mm:ss' format. You can also use one of the following “relaxed” syntaxes: 'hh:mm:ss', 'hh:mm', 'D hh:mm', 'D hh',
or 'ss'. Here D represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.
As a string with no delimiters in 'hhmmss' format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, '101112' is understood as
'10:11:12', but '109712' is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part)
and becomes '00:00:00'.
As a number in hhmmss format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, 101112 is understood as '10:11:12'. The following
alternative formats are also understood: ss, mmss, or hhmmss.


2nd option matches your need.
I give a link to the Reference Manual for version 8.0, but it is valid for your version too.
